# ROS: TurtleBot3 motors runs 60 seconds after message is seen in topic /cmd_vel

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, raspberry-pi

I am running ROS Kinetic, on a Turtlebot3 Burger with a Raspberry Pi3.

The goal here is to remotely control the Turtlebot from another Raspberry Pi. The remote controller Pi sends movement information over a socket connection.

I have delay problems when publishing into /cmd_vel (60 seconds delay) and again delay of 60 seconds from when the Twist message is echoed in the topic /cmd_vel to when the Turtlebot starts moving. I cannot locate why this 2 x 60 seconds delay occurs. I think that I might be pushing the raspberry pi too much.

If I do the following steps: 
The Turtlebot3 is the ROS MASTER.
1. From remote SSH into the Raspberry Pi --> roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch
2. From remote SSH into the Raspberry Pi -- >roslaunch turtlebot3_teleop turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch

Everything works fine no delays.

When I do: 
The Turtlebot3 is the ROS MASTER.
1. From remote SSH into the Raspberry Pi --> roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch
2. From remote SSH into the Raspberry Pi -- >python post_office.py //python script posted below. 
3. From remote SSH into the Raspberry Pi -- >rostopic echo /cmd_vel

The messages get into /cmd_vel with a 60 seconds delay. 
The Turtlebot3 starts moving after 120 seconds delay.

When I do: 
The REMOTE PC is the ROS MASTER.
1. roscore on remote pc
2. From remote SSH into the Raspberry Pi --> roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch
3. From remote SSH into the Raspberry Pi -- >python post_office.py //python script posted below. 
4. Remote pc -- >rostopic echo /cmd_vel

The messages get into /cmd_vel with a 0 seconds delay. 
The Turtlebot3 starts moving after 35 seconds delay.

env | grep ROS gives the following when Turtlebot3 is ROS MASTER:
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.39:11311
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/pi/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.39
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic

Here is the post_office.py running on the Turtlebot3.

```
import socket
import json
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
import thread
import time

HOST = ''
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print ('Connected by', addr)

twist = Twist()
lin = 0.0
ang = 0.0
pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=5) #queqe size can be adjusted maybe

def publish_cmd_vel():
    while not rospy.is_shutdown(): #checking the rospy.is_shutdown() flag and then doing work. You have to check is_shutdown() to check if your program should exit (e.g. if there is a Ctrl-C or otherwise).
        twist.linear.x = lin; twist.linear.y = 0; twist.linear.z = 0 #liniar has to be .x value to change
        twist.angular.x = 0; twist.angular.y = 0; twist.angular.z = ang #angular has to be .z value to change
        try:
            pub.publish(twist)
        except:
            print('unable to publish')

def recv_from_controller():
    while True:
        global lin, ang
        move_bytes = conn.recv(1024) #receive information as bytes
        move_info = json.loads(move_bytes) #decode into a dictionary
        lin = move_info['lin']
        ang = move_info['ang']
        print(type(lin), lin, type(ang), ang)


thread.start_new_thread( recv_from_controller, ())    

rospy.init_node('post_office', anonymous = False)

while True:     
    publish_cmd_vel()
```

Any ideas to why I get these delays?